# How can I send rest request to socket

Tags: java, spring, rest, websocket

I tried to create an API that send request via socket.

Code:

```
@Controller
public class GreetingController {
    @GetMapping("/x")
    public void send() {
        greeting(new HelloMessage("Admin", "bla"));
    }
    @MessageMapping("/hello")
    @SendTo("/topic/greetings")
    public Greeting greeting(HelloMessage message) {
        return new Greeting(HtmlUtils.htmlEscape(message.getName() + ": " + message.getMsg()));
    }
}
```

I don't understand how to send request via rest to websocket.
Can anyone explain why when I send a request to `/x` the websocket does not get `new HelloMessage`?

Comment: Define "doesn't work".

Comment: @DaveNewton The client that listen to socket do not get the message

Comment: Can you add your client code? It's likely something related to that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call another method from the same class, you just do that: call a method. This method call doesn't care whether the called method has annotations.

The greeting() method only sends a message when it's called from a websocket client posting a message to `/hello`.

To send a message programmatically, you use the SimpMessageTemplate, [as documented](http://%20https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#websocket-stomp-handle-send):

> What if you want to send messages to connected clients from any part of the application? Any application component can send messages to the brokerChannel. The easiest way to do so is to inject a SimpMessagingTemplate and use it to send messages. Typically, you would inject it by type, as the following example shows:

```
@Controller
public class GreetingController {

    private SimpMessagingTemplate template;

    @Autowired
    public GreetingController(SimpMessagingTemplate template) {
        this.template = template;
    }

    @RequestMapping(path="/greetings", method=POST)
    public void greet(String greeting) {
        String text = "[" + getTimestamp() + "]:" + greeting;
        this.template.convertAndSend("/topic/greetings", text);
    }

}
```